# Android - LocationManager digits after decimal

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location, decimal

I have a short question, when I get the location from LocationManager, the coordinates are obtained without any precision:

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,2000,10, this);
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    String msg = "New Latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+"New Longitude: "+location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and the result is:

> New Latitude: 19.0New Longitude: 51.0

How can I set how many digits after decimal I want to get?

Comment: Please look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html; there are ways of formatting latitude and longitude; then try it and let us know if it works. Coordinates are returned as doubles, so there is plenty of precision there. It's just a matter of using the correct way to convert the number to a string.

Comment: Try to display also `getProvider()` from `Location`, maybe you didn't get data from GPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was entering coordinates wrongly in Android Device Monitor.
When I put 51.02 it does what I described but when 51,02 is entered everything works just fine. Sorry all for trouble.